# How do I make XCFramework documentation fully available in "Developer Documentation"?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcframework, docc

I'm developing a fully documented framework. In its developing project, the documentation works perfectly. Although, when I add this framework to a project (with SPM or Cocoapods), if I `option + click` something defined in my framework I am not able to check its full content. The docstrings show up nicely, but the link "Open in Developer Documentation" is not available and if I click on one of the available links (for example, a function parameter type), it says "Page not available".

I have already tried to build the docs on the host app with `control + command + shift + d`, it builds all of the dependencies of my framework (which are all open-source, i.e the swift files are there) but my Framework doesn't even show up.

It doesn't make sense to me that this is not working, as I said, Xcode can actually find the docs but seems it can't find it when building.

I've found a similar question here on Stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to be the same issue, and there are no answers.

Am I'm missing something? Is there something that I must do in the host app? Or is there some lacking config when building the framework?

For example, in the picture (had to redact some info, sorry), if I click `APIEnvironment`, which is defined within my framework, I get a message of page not found. [image]